# Is it possible to keep a WKInterfaceButton depressed?

Tags: ios, watchkit

You can click on a WKInterfaceButton, but is there any way to keep it depressed?

Comment: What do you mean by depressed?

Comment: Instead of tapping, keeping the button depressed. Just like you would keep a keyboard button depressed to have it repeatedly typing a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official way to do this. Unfortunately, [WatchKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/index.html) and the [WKInterfaceButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceButton) are fairly limited at this time.

#### Outside the box options

With that said, you could use the [setBackgroundColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceButton/setBackgroundColor:) or [setBackgroundImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceButton/setBackgroundImage:) methods to switch the background of the button to represent a depressed state. You could also use a show/hide with a second button that could accomplish the same affect. The show/hide would be instant and could not be animated, but that may be sufficient for your needs.

Hopefully that helps shed some light.

Comment: From the user perspective, you still have to tap. I was trying to find some way, tone notified when the user "releases" a button, so some action could be performed until it is released.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand, but I can at least say with certainty that you cannot receive specific events such as `touchDown`. I think that's what you would need to be able to do to accomplish what you're attempting. WatchKit just doesn't support that type of functionality at the moment.